# Show simulator when running xcodebuild test in command line

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, xcuitest

Since Xcode 9, xcodebuild runs the simulators in headless mode (= the simulator is not launched in the foreground) which is a great improvement.

However, I need to debug an issue with xcodebuild and UI tests and would like to see what happens in the simulator. **Is it possible to force the simulator to be displayed when running tests with xcodebuild?**

Note: running in Xcode is not an answer :) because I cannot reproduce the issue in Xcode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by launching Xcode (right click) and open Developer Tool -> Simulator, while the tests are running in headless mode via xcodebuild.

This will show all the simulator screens which are running in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible but a little bit tricky

First of all you have to select your target and your target simulator

[image]

After that, you have to build your app for testing :

[image]

Go in your project's derived data and open `Build/Product` folder in terminal, for example :

> /Users/CURRENT_USER_FOLDER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_DERIVED_DATA/Build/Products

Retrieve your simulator id with `instruments -s devices` command :

[image]

Execute this command to run you test on your simulator

```
xcodebuild test-without-building \
    -xctestrun <yourfile.xctestrun> \
    -destination id=<iphoneID>
```

Test will launch on your simulator without using XCode and you will be able to see UI animations on your simulator